# Jumpy SwiftUI ScrollView on iOS 17 whenever its content size changes

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview, ios17

I have noticed a new ScrollView issue on iOS 17. It looks like a bug but I am not 100% sure.

I have submitted the same issue to Apple to ask and will revert here If I get the answer. If anyone else encountered the same issue and know how to fix/workaround it, please share

#### The issue as observed on iOS 17

[image: iOS 17]

#### No issue when running the same code on iOS 16/older

[image: iOS 16 or older]

#### The minimum reproducible code

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ScrollViewBugApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            TestView(counter: model.counter)
        }
    }
}

@MainActor class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var counter = 0
    
    init() {
        let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.3, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            Task { await self.incrementCounter() }
        }
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
    }
    
    private func incrementCounter() {
        counter += 1
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var counter: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider()
            
            Text("\(counter)")
            
            if counter % 2 == 0{
                Text("Even Number")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI it is best to avoid conditional Views which is what the `if` auto-generates by the `@ViewBuilder` of `body`. Instead, make the condition on the data itself. This change fixes the scroll glitch:

```
Text("\(counter) \(counter % 2 == 0 ? "Even Number" : "")")
```

FYI to use async/await in SwiftUI we don't use `Task {}`, we use the `.task` modifier or `.task(id:)` to cancel and restart when the `id` changes.

Also, `@StateObject` isn't designed to be a view model object, that's the job of the `View` struct. However, since you want to use async/await you don't even need an observable object to manage the async lifecycle anymore, `.task` handles that automatically.

If you change it to something like this, SwiftUI will run more efficiently because there is no object:

```
struct Counter {
    var value: Int = 0
    
    mutating func increment() {
        value += 1
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var counter = Counter()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView { // since this doesn't depend on counter it would be better to be placed in a parent View.
            TestView(counter: counter.value)
            .task {
                print("Starting timer")
                do {
                    while (true) {
                        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.3))
                        counter.increment()
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("Cancelled timer") // e.g. if this screen disappears
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
}

struct TestView: View {
    var counter: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider()
            
            Text("\(counter) \(counter % 2 == 0 ? "Even Number" : "")")
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```